# Use CanCan to limit amount of Items within a Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

A `Form` belongs_to `UserGroup`. Certain roles cannot create more then one `Form`, with type 'improvement_points' per `UserGroup`. I would like to implement this with CanCan (1.6.x). But how?

In my view and controller I'd like to be able to say:

```
link_to("New Form", new_form_path) if can? :create, Form, @user_group
```

Or anything similar, like `Form.new(:user_group => @user_group)` will do.

Relevant part from my ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.is_coach?
      cannot :create, Form, :type => "improvement_points" do |form|
        # Allow no more than one Form per group.
        Form.where(:user_group_id => user_group.id).count > 0
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Problem is that I don't know how to pass in the context for the
user_group_id. I have attempted [Rianbs description on this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/133), but this seems not to apply to my case, since I need to specifically check the amount of Items to create.

Is cancan the correct tool for this? I already have some validations in place on the `Form model` to enforce this one-per-group behaviour on a lower level; should I ask the Form model instead of Ability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe cancan can do this, but it feels like you're pushing it.  I would just put this logic in the controller.

```
def create
  if condition_that_is_hard_to_write_in_ability_rb?
    raise CanCan::AccessDenied, "Helpful message about what to do instead"
  end
end
```